# How to perform some action during several seconds?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nstimer

I would like to know how can I display a view for about 3-4 seconds in iOS 5 ?
I searched on the web, I found NSTimer but I don't know how to use it in my purpose...

I think a have to create my view, display it, then start the timer or something like that during 3-4 seconds, then hide my view when my timer has finished.
But how to use this famous timer ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` to do this.

```
[myView performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:3.0];
```

Comment: Oh great it was finally so simple !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    int someSeconds = 3;
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissView) withObject:self afterDelay:someSeconds];
```

and dissmissView looks something like:

```
- (void)dismissView{
[theView viewRemoveFromSuperView];
}
```